# Similarities between the Schrödinger equation and the differential equation modelling exponential growth

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

The Schrödinger equation looks like this:

$${\displaystyle i\hbar {\frac {\partial }{\partial t}}|\psi (t)\rangle ={\hat {H}}|\psi (t)\rangle }$$

and the differential equation for exponential growth looks like this:

$$\frac{{dy}}{{dt}} = k \cdot y.$$

We can see the similarities that they both have; a function under the derivative sign on the LHS and again that function also appears on the RHS with "something" multiplied in front.

We know that the solution to the differential equation regarding the exponential growth is the function:

$$f(x) = e^x.$$

In contrast to the differential equation that models exponential growth the Schrödinger equation also has the imaginary unit $i$ in it.

The "function" $e^{ix}$ looks like a helix when graphed in $3D$, the real part is $cos(x)$ and the imaginary $sin(x)$.

[image]

If we were trying to find the solution a function modelling a free particle we put:

$$
\hat{H} = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}.
$$

The solution is than of the form:

$$
\psi(x,t) = A e^{i(kx - \omega t)} + B e^{-i(kx + \omega t)} 
$$

and this also "looks" like a helix when plotted.

**Question:**

Is there some physical interpretation why the two equations are similar? Because I think that is is too much mathematical coincidences happening at once (if mathematical coincidences exist at all in general).

**Appendix; they are both eigenfunctions:**

The wave function is an eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian operator with corresponding eigenvalue(s) $E$.

The exponential function could also be considered an eigenfunction:

Consider the derivative operator $\frac{d}{dt}$ with eigenvalue equation $$\frac{d}{dt}f(t) = \lambda f(t).$$

This differential equation can be solved by multiplying both sides by  $\frac{dt}{f(t)}$ and integrating. Its solution, the exponential function $$f(t) = f_0 e^{\lambda t},$$ is the eigenfunction of the derivative operator, where $f_0$ is a parameter that depends on the boundary conditions.

Comment: As you have pointed out yourself, $\exp(ix)$ is *not* in fact exponential in $x$ (i.e. it does not give exponential growth or decay) but rather represents *wave* behavior. The Schrödinger equation is precisely an equation trying to reconcile the wave-like and particle-like aspects of quantum objects.

Comment: The structure of the SE simply reflects the fact that we are describing an ensemble in which the total number of elements stays the same, i.e. the norm of the wave function stays the same over time (and we usually set it to 1). There is absolutely no growth going on here because that would make no logical sense for an ensemble theory.

Comment: Actually there is a derivation for schrodinger equation (pseudo derivation) which uses the Classical SHM model analogy

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, Re, "exp($ix$)" is not in fact exponential." Uh, sure, but just in case any newbies come here; Hey newbies! Listen up. Exp(...) is _always_ The Exponential Function regardless of what "..." you give it as an argument. We don't call it that because of how it models exponential growth. It's the other way around. We call "exponential growth" by that name because it can be modeled using an exponential function of time. We call the function "exponential" because its argument is used as an _exponent:_ $\exp(x)=e^x$.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, thank you for the comment. My comment was written with the phrasing "exponential growth" in the title of the post in mind, but I realize upon second reading that what I wrote can be (perhaps grossly) misinterpreted. (Although I might argue that one should not call $e^{\ln(x)}$ "exponential" but someone else can fight that fight =P )

Comment: I am sorry, I did not mean to imply that the function $e^x$ has anything de facto to do with the Schrödinger equation and I am aware that the $exp(ix)$ has nothing to do with exponential growth, it was just an intro to my question. I was more interested if there were physical connections between the two differential equations due to the similarity of the forms that both differential equations posses. Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly stated, the Schrödinger equation of a free particle gives rise to something that's oscillating (i.e. a wave), while the equation for exponential growth gives rise to something that is, well, exponentially growing. To understand why both phenomena are very closely related, we don't even have to talk about Quantum Mechanics. It's enough to consider the good old harmonic oscillator.

Consider a mass $m$ attached to a spring. When you pull the mass away from its stable position (let's set it to $x=0$), the spring wants to pull it back. So there is a force acting on the mass that is proportional to the displacement $x$ that it acting in the direction opposite to the direction of displacement:
$$F = -kx$$
According to Newton's second law, we thus have
$$m \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -kx.$$
This is the differential equation for a harmonic oscillator. As you know, the most general solution is
$$x(t) = A \sin(\omega t) + B \cos(\omega t)$$
where $\omega$ is the frequency (which is directly related to $k$ and $m$ via $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$) and $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary constants. We can also write the solution in terms of complex exponentials:
$$x(t) = C e^{i\omega t} + D e^{-i \omega t}$$
where again, $C$ and $D$ are some constants. If we still want to interpret $x$ as a displacement in space, we have to choose $C$ and $D$ such that $x$ is a real number. But if we set $C=0$, this is also the solution of the differential equation
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = -i \omega x$$
If we multiply both sides by $i$, we see that this is of the same form as the Schrödinger equation for an energy Eigenstate:
$$i\hbar \frac{d\psi}{dt} = E \psi$$
This equation also describes something that is oscillating, only now in the complex plane.
Now, let's go back to the Harmonic oscillator:
$$m \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -kx.$$
What happens when we change the sign on the right-hand side?
$$m \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = kx$$
This would describe a very weird "spring" where you get a force that acts in the same direction as the displacement. Pulling slightly on the mass will produce a force that pulls the mass further out of its rest position, creating an even larger displacement, creating an even larger force, and so on. It should be easy to imagine that the displacement would blow up rapidly. In fact the solution is exponential growth:
$$x(t) = A e^{\xi t}$$
with $\xi = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$.
The differential equation for this "reverse harmonic oscillator" is actually equivalent to the usual equation for exponential growth:
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \xi x$$
Because when you have an exponential as the solution, each derivative just pulls down the prefactor of the argument, so
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \xi x$$
and
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \xi^2 x$$
describe the exact same system.

I hope this is somewhat close to the kind of physical intuition you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Will still keep it open for a little while more if someone else has some more connections.